# How to open a binary file stored in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, binary, google-cloud-storage, word2vec

I have generated a binary file with the [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/), stored the resulting `.bin` file to my GCS bucket, and ran the following code in my App Engine app handler:

```
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 'r')
    content = gcs_file.read().encode("utf-8")
    """ call word2vec with content so it doesn't need to read a file itself, as we don't have a filesystem in GAE """
```

Fails with this error:
`content = gcs_file.read().encode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)`

A similar decode error happens if I try `gcs_file.read()`, or `gcs_file.read().decode("utf-8").encode("utf-8")`.

Any ideas on how to read a binary file from GCS?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling encode? If it's bytes, it's already encoded.

Comment: not if it is bytes you do not *know* what it is, if it is a `png` then it is definitely **not** already encoded using a character encoding. Unless it was converted to `Base64` or `UUE`, but I am pretty sure from the code and the question that is **not** the case either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is binary then it will not take a character encoding, which is what `UTF-8` is. `UTF-8` is just one possible binary encoding of the `Unicode` specification for character sets ( `String` data ). You need to go back and read up on what `UTF-8` and `ASCII` represent and how they are used.

If it was not text data that was encoded with a specific encoding then it is not going to magically just `decode`, which is why you are getting that error. `can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 15` is not a valid `ASCII` value.

Comment: Fair enough. What confused me, and the lesson I learned from your answer is that binary files are already encoded. Thanks.